# MySQL - Select on varchar column with 0 (zero) as criteria returns all rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Sorry in advance - this seems like a really dumb question. But...

If I run a `select` query on a `varchar()` column, but use zero for the column value in the `where` clause - why does it return all rows?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  person varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, person) VALUES (1, "Alice");
INSERT INTO test (id, person) VALUES (2, "Bob");

SELECT * FROM test where person = 0;
```

I would expect this to either return an error, or an empty result set. Instead, it returns ***all rows?!?!***

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression:

```
person = 0
```

contains 2 operands of different data types.
In this case MySql does implicit conversion as it is explained in [12.2 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)
So a value like `'Bob'`is implicitly converted to a floating-point value and this value is `0`.
There are cases where a string will be converted to a value different than `0`, like when the string begins with a numeric part and then that numeric part is its converted value, so:

- `'12abc6'` will be converted to `12` and
- `'5.6xyz0'` will be converted to `5.6`

An *exception* to this rule is a string like `'2e3'` which is interpreted as `2 * 10^3` (scientific notation) so it is converted to `2000`.
 
In your code all the names are converted to `0`, so the condition becomes:

```
0 = 0
```

which is always `true`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is called *implicit conversion*. Since you are asking MySQL to compare a string with an integer, it convers the string to number, then compares the result.

And it turns out that, in MySQL, any string that does not start with digit is converted to `0`. This matches on your `where` predicate, hence the results that you are seeing.

As a general rule of thumb: do not rely on implicit casting; when passing litteral values in your queries, do use the proper datatype (here, `0` should be `'0'`). When comparing table columns, do cast as needed.

Here is a [small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=862e67d8a7c14c9ee3d4efa94b105a4e) of int/string comparisons.

```
select 
    'foo' = '0',  -- false (as expected)
    'foo' = 0,    -- true!
    '0foo' = 0    -- true ("0foo" starts with "0")
```

```
'foo' = '0' | 'foo' = 0 | '0foo' = 0
----------: | --------: | ---------:
          0 |         1 |          1
```

Comment: GMB - thank you for your excellent answer - I appreciate you taking the time to provide that much detail and clarity. I would have selected your answer as the accepted one, but since you had 10k more reputation than @forpas - I hope you don't mind me giving the check to him instead. Both answers are great, and equally deserving.

Comment: @mattstuehler: your are welcome! I like the way you broke that tie.